# Very lagging when using openlayers 3.16.0 loading a large floor map on Android post-Kitkat webview

Tags: android, android-webview, openlayers-3

I am trying to load a very large floormap image (PNG of size 618KB and resolution 7062 x 7582) using openlayers 3.16.0 on a Android 5.1.1 device.

I can hardly scroll on the WebView to pan the floor map. Sometimes the app would crash itself. When I inspect the webview using chrome, it shows messages of:

> Deferred long-running timer task(s) to improve scrolling smoothness.
>   See crbug.com/574343.

I have enabled hardware acceleration on the activity of the webview and here are the WebSettings of the webview:

```
WebSettings webSettings = getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);

webSettings.setAppCachePath(dir.getPath());
webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
webSettings.setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 1024 * 50);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
} else {
    setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}

enableCrossDomain();

setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

May I know how to improve the performance on loading the floormap using openlayers 3 on Android WebView?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly this happens because it's a Vector layer with a lot of info, so it's hard to render. In order to improve the performance, you could try with a Tile layer made of .png images:

```
  var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    name:"Mapa",
    isBaseLayer:true,
    visible:true,
    source: new ol.source.OSM({
     url:'../layers/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
    }),
  }));
```

With the help of [this code](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-map.html), you can build a simple app for yourself to export the map into .png images. Remember to save them with the correct folder format (z/x/y). Good luck!